# How to use t.ppf()? which are the arguments?

Tags: python, distribution

I couldn't understand how to properly use `t.ppf`, could someone please explain it to me?

I have to use this information

- scipy.stats.t
- scipy.stats
- a mean of 100
- a standard deviation of 0.39
- N = 851 (851 samples)

When I'm asked to calculate the (95%) margin of error using t.ppf() will the code look like below?

```
cutoff1 = t.ppf(0.05,100,0.36,850)
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [reference docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html), the arguments to `t.ppf` are `q`, `df`, `loc`, and `scale`.  The `df` argument is [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)), which is usually the sample size minus 1 for a single population sampling problem. Since `ppf` calculates the inverse cumulative distribution function, by definition a result of `x` for a given `q`-value and `df` means `P{T <= x} = q`, i.e, there is probability `q` of getting outcomes less than or equal to `x` from a `T` distribution with the given `loc` and `scale`. The `loc` (mean) and `scale` (standard deviation) arguments are optional, and default to 0 and 1, respectively.

To get a 95% margin of error, you want 5% of the probability to be in the tails of the distribution.  This is usually done symmetrically so that 2.5% is in each tail, so you would use `q` values of 0.025 and 0.975 for the lower and upper cutoff points respectively.  For your particular problem, the code would look something like:

```python
from scipy.stats import t

n = 851
mean = 100
std_dev = 0.39

lower_cutoff = t.ppf(0.025, n - 1, loc = mean, scale = std_dev)  # =>  99.23452406698323
upper_cutoff = t.ppf(0.975, n - 1, loc = mean, scale = std_dev)  # => 100.76547593301677
```

Comment: 95%CI is mentioned to be mean+/-1.96*SE where SE = SD/sqrt(N) ;  See here: http://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic4/4h/4h_2content_11.html  ; By this formula, one get these values: 99.973796 and 100.02620329 ; Why are these values so much different from values obtained in this answer?

Comment: Actually values obtained in the answer (99.234 and 100.765) are obtained with formula of mean+/-1.96*SE if SE=SD/1 i.e. when N=1 (so that sqrt(1) is 1)

Comment: @rnso The question explicitly asked about `t.ppf` rather than `t.interval`, so I assumed they were asking for percentiles under the assumption of normality with known mean but unknown variance, and *not* about a CI. The difference is a factor of sqrt(n) for the CI half-width. `t.interval(0.05, n - 1, loc = mean, scale = std_dev)` yields a CI of `(99.97553713440418, 100.02446286559582)`, in line with your comment. Note that using 1.96 assumes the t distribution has asymptotically converged to normal -- not a bad assumption for n = 851 -- but only gives three significant digits.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks.

Comment: `The df argument is degrees of freedom, which is usually the sample size minus 1 for a single population sampling problem.`  Why minus 1?

Comment: @NoName Degrees of freedom reflect how many independent pieces of information are available when you go to estimate the variance. True variance is based on deviations around the actual (but usually unknown) mean µ. Sample variance is calculated using deviations from x-bar, the sample mean. Given the sample mean, any subset of size n-1 can contain any values whatsoever, but the n’th value is then constrained make the average come out to x-bar. Consequently, your estimate of s^2 contains only n-1 independent pieces of information when based on x-bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain you have to use standard error instead, which is std/sqrt(n)